# How to preview Document file in Razor view C# MVC with header Referer

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have tried the below code but, I'm not able to the passed header in the URL, I need to pass the header for bucket access

```
 <iframe class="doc" src="https://docs.google.com/gview?url=https://example.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/sample.docx&embedded=true"></iframe>
```

I want to pass `Referer': 'http:/example.in/` header while send the request from our website

Comment: Sounds like you'll need to point your iframe to your own Controller, and then in your Controller Action do a WebRequest to get the content you need and return as html.

Comment: Is there any possibility of using ajax? @Gary

Comment: Unlikely, as this would be subject to CORS restrictions.

Comment: Yes, i have received this error, do you have any other solution

Comment: Why can't you do your own Controller action?

Comment: Because I want to send request from the client-side, i don't want to save file in our server

Comment: Ok, unfortunately without control over what headers are sent for an IFRAME, I'm not sure this is possible.